# Add the same image more times to a pdf with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I generate pdf with jsPDF, and I multiple some images in many times. Thus the file size is getting larger and larger, although there is only some images, but several times.

Is there any way to store these images once, but show more times? Absolutely the pdf format ready for this?

I use this code with jsPDF, it is the default image adding:

```
var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASA...';
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Paranyan loves jsPDF");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with this [merge request](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/pull/120) from [burnburnrocket](https://github.com/burnburnrocket).

Comment: It looks good, but... I use bower for my project, and I don't know, how should I check out this version... Could you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I declare two div with different id, like:

```
<div id="div1"><div>

<div id="div2"><div>

var doc = new jsPDF('a4');
var img=[];
var requiredPages = 2 // count of div
for (var i = requiredPages; i >= 1; i--) {
   //console.log(i)
   html2canvas(document.getElementById("newrow"+i), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            img.push(imgData);
           // console.log('Report Image URL: '+imgData);
             //210mm wide and 297mm high

            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 5, 210, 290);
            (img.length!=requiredPages)
            {
              doc.addPage();
            }


            if(img.length==requiredPages)
            {
            doc.save('compare.pdf');  
            }

            //doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
        }
   });
}
```